# `ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression` in PL/SQL loop with function (12.1.0.2)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ojdbc

Can someone explain why this PL/SQL block returns an ORA-00979 "not a GROUP BY expression" error?  I feel like I am taking crazy pills.

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN ( SELECT substr(o.object_name,1,30) oname
             FROM   user_objects o
             GROUP BY substr(o.object_name,1,30)
             ) LOOP
      NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

> ```
> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
> ORA-06512: at line 2
> 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
> ```

If I wrap it in a `CREATE PROCEDURE` it works...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mattp AS
BEGIN
  FOR r IN ( SELECT substr(o.object_name,1,30) oname
             FROM   user_objects o
             GROUP BY substr(o.object_name,1,30)
             ) LOOP
      NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I am on 12.1.0.2.  I do not get the error in 18c (Oracle LiveSQL).

Has anyone else encountered this?  I thought in 12c that PL/SQL used the same SQL parser as the SQL engine?

Comment: Hmm. It works fine for me on 12.2.0.1

Comment: Weirder and weirder.  It works if I connect to the same database & user from SQL\*Navigator.  I only get the error in SQL\*Developer.  I guess it has something to do with JDBC.

Comment: Tried it as an anonymous block in Oracle 11,2.0.4, 12.1, and 18.0, worked in all of them.

Comment: I am chalking it up to a SQL\*Developer / JDBC bug.  I wonder if I can vote to close my own question?